# Trouble web scraping Google Sheets in R using RSelenium and RCurl

Tags: r, iframe, web-scraping, rcurl, rselenium

My ultimate goal is to web scrape the **Standings** page of [The Puzzled Pint](http://www.puzzledpint.com/standings/) for `Montreal`.

I think I need to dynamically scrape (*e.g.* use `RSelenium`) since the table I'm interested in is a JavaScript `iframe` - part of a web page that displays content independent of its container.

Some have suggested that scraping directly from the source of these `iframes` is the way to go. I used the web developer `Inspector` tool in my `firefox` browser to find the `src=` which happens to be `Google Sheets`.

[image]

First, use `robots.txt` to make sure we're allowed to scrape it from `Google Sheets`:

```
library(robotstxt)
paths_allowed("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true#gid=203220308")
```

Now that I know I have permission, I tried the `RCurl` package. It's simple to get the first page:

```
library(RCurl)
sheet <- getForm("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub", hl = "en_US", key = "1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U", output = "csv", .opts = list(followlocation = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
df <- read.csv(textConnection(sheet))
head(df)
```

However, when you click any of the other `Month/Year` links on this `Google Sheet` the `gid=` of the url changes. For example, for October 2018 it's now:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true#gid=1367583807
```

I'm not sure if it's possible to scrape `widget`'s with `RCurl`? If it is I'd love to hear how.

So it looks like I will most likely need to use `RSelenium` to do this.

```
library(RSelenium)
# connect to a running server
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100",
  port = 4445L
)
remDr$open()
# navigate to the site of interest
remDr$navigate("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true#gid=203220308")
```

My problem is trying to get the `HTML` for the table on this page, the following was [suggested on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932542/how-to-read-an-html-table-using-rselenium) but doesn't work for me (It doesn't return the expected output, just `Month/Year` metadata from the links/elements)?

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
readHTMLTable(doc)
```

I believe I need to navigate to the inner frame but not sure how to do this?
For example, when looking for the CSS tag for this table with `SelectorGadget` in `chrome` it gives me a warning that it's an iframe and to be able to select within it I need to click a link.

[image]

When I use this link with `readHTMLTable()` I get the correct information I want:

```
remDr$navigate("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=203220308")
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
readHTMLTable(doc)
```

[image]

This presents a problem as I need to use `RSelenium` to navigate through the different pages/tables of the previous link (the `iframe` widget):

```
remDr$navigate("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true#gid=203220308")
```

To navigate through the different pages/tables I use [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) to find the `CSS` tags

```
# find all elements/links
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", ".switcherItem")
# Select the first link (October 2018)
webElem_01 <- webElems[[1]]
```

Then using [TightVNC viewer](https://www.tightvnc.com/) I verified I was highlighting the correct element then "click" the element (in this case the `October 2018` link).

```
webElem_01$highlightElement()
```

[image]

```
webElem_01$clickElement()
```

Since I can see that the page changed on `TightVNC` I assume there would be no more steps required before capturing/scraping here but as mentioned I need a way of programmatically navigating to the inner `iframe` of each of these pages.

### UPDATE

Okay I figured out how to navigate to the inner frame using the `remDr$switchToFrame()` command but I cannot seem to figure out how to navigate back to the outer frame in order to "click" the next link and repeat the process. My current hacky attempt would involve me navigating back to the main page and repeating this process many times:

```
# navigate to the main page
remDr$navigate("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true#gid=690408156")
# look for table
tableElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "pageswitcher-content")
# switch to table
remDr$switchToFrame(tableElem)
# parse html
doc <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
readHTMLTable(doc)

# how do I switch back to the outer frame?
# the remDr$goBack() command doesn't seem to do this

# workaround is to navigate back to the main page then navigate back to the second page and repeat process
remDr$navigate("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true#gid=690408156")
webElems <- remDr$findElements(using = "css", ".switcherItem")
webElem_01 <- webElems[[1]]
webElem_01$clickElement()
tableElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", "pageswitcher-content")
# switch to table
remDr$switchToFrame(tableElem)
# parse html
doc2 <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
readHTMLTable(doc2)
```

Comment: You _could_ just request access to the google sheets. Most site owners are pretty friendly and if you explain your use-case you might not have to do any of this scraping at all. The non-HTML views for all those URLs are locked down (I checked :-) but all the content is CCA-NCSA-3.0 so they aren't restricting the use of the data. feedback@puzzledpint.com will likely be much quicker than the web spelunking (though you've done a  job triaging.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to request access. I agree this would be the simplest way but this is also mostly for myself to learn RSelenium :)

Answer (score 2):

Having noted what I did in the comment, this works for ~19 of the URLs:

```
library(googlesheets4)
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("http://www.puzzledpint.com/standings/")

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//iframe[contains(@src, 'sheet')]") %>% 
  html_attr("src") -> gsheet_urls

gsheet_urls[grepl("output=html", gsheet_urls, fixed=TRUE)] %>% 
  lapply(function(x) {
    read.csv(
      file =gsub("=true", "=false", gsub("=html", "=csv", x)),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  }) -> nineteen

str(nineteen, 1)
## List of 19
##  $ :'data.frame': 8 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 37 obs. of  7 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 35 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 62 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 34 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 30 obs. of  11 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 24 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 11 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 9 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 13 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 36 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 9 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 13 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 29 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 45 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 34 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 22 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ :'data.frame': 14 obs. of  6 variables:
```

All of the `pubhtml` ones have had CSV exporting expressly denied without permission.

Comment: Thank's Bob! As the author of `splashr` (an alternative to `RSelenium` that I haven't tried yet) I'm wondering why you didn't suggest a solution with that tool?

Comment: The `Rvest` + `googlesheets4` method only works for the ~30% of the tables (19/63), and only for the current month. Requesting access to the google sheets from PuzzledPint (IMO the *least fun* way) or my updated solution with `RSelenium` appear to be the best solutions at the moment

Comment: Aye, I noted the "~19" in my answer. The reason for no `splashr` answer is that I'm not writing all the Lua code necessary for doing this :-) There are nuances to groups of tables, each requiring custom Selenium processing and/or custom `splashr` Splash Lua code. That's asking quite a bit of an SO contributor IMO.

Comment: That's fair enough. I was wondering if it was the length/complexity of code that it would require or if it was for some other reason (e.g. akin to using a shovel to kill a fly). I appreciate you taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need selenium just extract `gid` or `pageUrl` from the page source

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pub?output=html&widget=true
```

example code

```
items.push(
{
  name: "November 2018",
  pageUrl: "https:\/\/docs.google.comm\/.....&gid=690408156",
  gid: "690408156",
  initialSheet: ("690408156" == gid)
});
items.push(
{
  name: "October 2018",
  pageUrl: "https:\/\/docs.google.com\/.....&gid=1367583807",
  gid: "1367583807",
  initialSheet: ("1367583807" == gid)
});
```

result urls:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=690408156
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o1PlLIQS8v-XSuEz1eqZB80kcJk9xg5lsbueB7mTg1U/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=1367583807
```

Comment: This doesn't look like R code to me, did you use the terminal? How did you go about finding these `gid` numbers from the page source `programmatically`? So say, for example, next month a new `gid` was generated a `regex` search grabs this and appends it to your `items.push()` code.